# Register third party- custom component with react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using `react-hook-form` and using third party `DatePicker`. Since it's a custom component using it as a controlled component to register it. This works fine

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="reviewStartDate"
    render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value } }) => (
        <DatePicker
            className={`form-control ${errors.reviewStartDate ? 'is-invalid' : ''}`}
            customInput={<input />}
            wrapperClassName="datePicker"
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            selected={value ? new Date(value) : ''}
            dateFormat='dd-MMM-yyyy'
        />
    )}
/>
```

Similarly/however, I am using thirdparty `Multiselect`. Here the value is not being registered. It does show the selected value but when I submit the form the value is not present in data.

```
<Controller
    control={control}
    name="rootCauseAnalysisCategory"
    render={({ field: { value } }) => (
        <Multiselect
            options={rootCauseAnalysisCategorys}
            isObject={false}
            showCheckbox={true}
            hidePlaceholder={true}
            closeOnSelect={false}
            selectedValues={value}
        />
    )}
/>
```

Similarly

Comment: The problem here is, that the `onChange` handler is missing and so RHF can't update the form state. Does your `<MultiSelect />` have some kind of onChange handler?

Comment: I added `onChange`, `onBlur`, `customInput` still doesn't work. No my `<MultiSelect/>` doesn't have `multiselect-react-dropdown`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `<MultiSelect />` component has `onSelect` and `onRemove` props, so you can just pass `onChange` to them. This will work because they both have the signature that the first argument is an array containing the current selected values.

```
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="rootCauseAnalysisCategory"
  defaultValue={[]}
  render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
    <Multiselect
      options={rootCauseAnalysisCategorys}
      isObject={false}
      showCheckbox={true}
      hidePlaceholder={true}
      closeOnSelect={false}
      onSelect={onChange}
      onRemove={onChange}
      selectedValues={value}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Basic (forked)]

**UPDATE**

If you want to access the current value for `rootCauseAnalysisCategory`, you have to use `watch`. Please note, that it is also important to either provide a `defaultValue` at the `<Controller />` field level or call `useForm` with `defaultValues`. In the example i passed the `defaultValue` at the field level.

```
function App() {
  const { control, handleSubmit, watch } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const rootCauseAnalysisCategorys = ["Category 1", "Category 2"];

  const rootCauseAnalysisCategory = watch("rootCauseAnalysisCategory");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="rootCauseAnalysisCategory"
          defaultValue={[]}
          render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
            <Multiselect
              options={rootCauseAnalysisCategorys}
              isObject={false}
              showCheckbox={true}
              hidePlaceholder={true}
              closeOnSelect={false}
              onSelect={onChange}
              onRemove={onChange}
              selectedValues={value}
            />
          )}
        />

        {rootCauseAnalysisCategory?.includes("Category 1") && <p>Category 1</p>}

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Controller multiselect-react-dropdown (forked)]

Comment: Thx, this works, but now I am into a new problem. How can I reference this value? It says `rootCauseAnalysisCategory` not defined

Comment: I need a bit more context to answer this question. How or where do you want to use or reference the value in the component?

Comment: Like I want to show one field depending on what value does `rootCauseAnalysisCategory` has.   `{ rootCauseAnalysisCategory.includes('something') && <div>show me</div> }`

Comment: I updated my answer to include the new requirements.

Comment: thx, I am also using `watch` currently was thinking if there is an alternate way, since `watch` doesn't contain the initial values. Like if the first time form is loaded or if I edit the form the `rootCauseAnalysisCategory` would be empty, though it would show up in `Multiselect` but your `<div>` won't show up

Comment: currently, I am using a hack to resolve this, i.e. if I set any `dummy` values in `useEffect` the watch is triggered and `div` will show up

Comment: For this use case it is better to provide the `defaultValues` to `useForm`. So if you are editing a form you can just pass all your form field values to `useForm` and all your inputs/fields will have those values on initial render. Here is the updated [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-multiselect-react-dropdown--with-watch-forked-h354s?file=/src/index.js).

Comment: yes, I did put the value it was working. But somehow not working in my code, trying to figure out what's happening. Thx for the codesandbox.